# Compute $F^{'}(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Compute $F^{'}(x) $ where
>
> $F(x) =\int _{-x}^x \dfrac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}$

Let $g(y)=\dfrac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}$

Thus $F^{'}(x)=g(x).1-g(-x).(-1)=\dfrac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x}-\dfrac{1-e^{x^2}}{x}=\dfrac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}$

But the answer given is $2\times \dfrac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}$

Where is that $2$ coming from ?Am I wrong?Please help.

Comment: Note that the integrand itself is changing with $x$, and the expression above does not account for that. The complete rule for differentiation under the integral is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), try working the problem out with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
F'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x}^x \frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}\,dy\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}\right)\right|_{y=x}\frac{d(x)}{dx}-\left.\left(\frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}\right)\right|_{y=-x}\frac{d(-x)}{dx}+\int_{-x}^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}\right)\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}+\int_{-x}^x e^{-xy}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}+\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: yes you are right ;I missed that third term

Comment: How did you get that rule ?Can you please share a link or so

Comment: I was asking how did you write the expression of $F^{'}(x)$

Comment: [SEE HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: You're quite welcome. My pleasure. -Mark